# SQL: Update Column Value with Value from Another Column ONLY if the Column Value is Equal to Certain Values

Tags: sql, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

This is the logic I'm trying to implement in SQL code:

1. Replace values from Req column with values from Phase column ONLY IF
2. The value in Phase column is equivalent to a predetermined list of values OTHERWISE
3. Keep the original value in Req column

   - I only want to replace the value in Req column if the value in Phase column is equal to C1, C2, C3, or C4

Below shows a sample of the table I'm trying to create:

[image]

I've successfully achieved the above in Python code (see below).  But now I need to do the same with SQL and I'm stuck.

```
phasename_dictionary = {'C1':'C1', 'C2':'C2', 'C3':'C3', 'C4':'C4'}
df.loc[df['phase'].isin(phasename_dictionary.keys()), 'req'] = df['phase'].map(phasename_dictionary)
```

Comment: can you also tag the database involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple `update` statement with a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    req = phase
WHERE  phase IN ('C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4')
```